# In what condition would a thread exit or stop running

Tags: linux, multithreading, networking, client-server

I am writing a server application in which there is a thread deployed to read/write many sockets connecting to clients. My manager tells me that it is not a good design, because if the thread  aborts due to unknown reason then all the read/write work will stop forever.

So I wonder in what conditions will a thread abort, except the case we return from the Run() function of a thread. Do we need consider the case that the thread stops running abnormally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. One thread per client can be a bad thing scalability wise, especially if the thread doesn't do that much work per client. In that circumstance it can be better to have a thread that handles a number of clients, the idea to achieve a good balance between the number of threads and having them do a decent amount of work.

If on the other hand each thread is doing a lot of work per client then one thread isn't such a bad idea, the overhead of the thread not being significant in comparison to the work load.

So setting that aside, a thread will abort if your code is written so that the thread returns or self-terminates. If another thread in your program knows the thread's handle/id then the library you're using may have a function with a name like thread_kill(). That would allow that other thread to kill this thread, though that's almost always a bad idea.

So as far as I'm concerned your thread will only abort and disappear if you've written your code to make that happen deliberately.

Handling exceptions is probably best done in its entirety within the thread where the exception arose. I've never tried to do otherwise (still writing in pure C), but the word is that it's difficult to handle them outside the thread. Irrespective of whether each thread handles one or many clients you still have to handle all errors and events within thread.

It may be simpler to get that correct if you write I so that a thread handles handles a single client. Getting it wrong could lead to a thread getting into a stalled state (eg waiting for the client that is listening too) and accumulating those as time goes past will eventually kill your whole system.

Comment: bazza, suppose there is a memory-fault error happened while the thread is running and the code didn't catch the error, so the thread will be killed immediately by the system? Will an error happened in run() function of one of the threads affect the whole process and cause the process to abort?

Comment: If you don't catch and handle an error like a memory fault (do you mean a seg fault?) there and then the OS has no choice but to step in and do it for you (normally by killing your whole application...). Runtimes like JAVA or C# AFAIK look after you to some extent but they also have to catch and deal with the catastrophic errors that your code ignores (eg null references?). Essentially you need a thorough error handling mechanism of last resort per thread that can either recover or gracefully terminate in the face of errors/exceptions that you've not handled elsewhere in the thread.

Comment: Best to not have errors like that arise in the first place. Handling errors is no substitute for error free code...

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing a server application in which there is a thread deployed to read/write many sockets connecting to clients.

Not a good design. There should be at least one thread *per client,* in some circumstances two: one to read and one to write. If you're dealing in blocking I/O, servicing one client could block out all the others. (If you're dealing in non-blocking I/O you don't need threads at all.)

> My manager tells me that it is not a good design, because if the thread aborts due to unknown reason then all the read/write work will stop forever.

He's right, for more reasons than he is advancing.

Comment: thanks. But I am confused about the exit of a thread. Suppose there is a memory-fault error happened while the thread is running and the code didn't catch the error, will the thread be killed immediately by the system? Will an error happened in run() function of one of the threads affect the whole process and cause the process to abort?

Comment: A multi client thread is certainly best off using non-blocking I/O for the reason EJP gives. However having no threads means that the throughput is limited to the performance of a single CPU core, very unscalable.